# returning instanced class + babel JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm building a "library" on JS, and it is mandatory to be only one .js file.

I just started to build, and i got this until now:

app-es6/main.js

```
class Sjs {

    create(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    }

}
```

index.html

```
<script src="app/main.js"></script>

<script>
    let sjs = new Sjs();
    sjs.create({
        type: 'select'
    });
</script>
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

### What i need to do:

1) The class should not be instantiated in html, the instance should come ready from js, so i can just type sjs.create(), like jQuery, moment, etc.

2) If i need to import more JS files, to build somehting more structured, can i "wrap" to a single js, minimized?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) The class should not be instantiated in html, the instance should come ready from js, so i can just type sjs.create(), like jQuery, moment, etc.

Just put it in the `main.js`, after the `class` declaration:

```
let sjs = new Sjs();
```

`let` at global scope creates a global variable (though not a property on the global object [usually accessed as `window` on browsers]). If you want that property as well, use `var` instead of `let` or assign to `window.sjs` (which will also create a global variable; all properties on the global object are globals, it's just that as of ES2015, not all globals are properties on the global object).

That said, if it's a singleton, there isn't much benefit to using `class`. It's probably also worth noting that jQuery and MomentJS both expose *functions* (`jQuery`/`$`, `moment`), not non-callable objects.

> 2) If i need to import more JS files, to build somehting more structured, can i "wrap" to a single js, minimized?

You're looking for a *bundler*, like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org), [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org), etc. They have plugins for integrating with [Babel](https://babeljs.io), doing minification, ...